# Open-form and Closed form

Tags: algorithm, math

How can an open-form of recurrence be converted into its equivalent closedform.
Furthermore, what are some commonly used closed-forms that are
usually used efficiently.

Comment: What forms? WinForms? Please be a little more specific by adding some context.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are talking about recursive functions and math.

e.g. consider the following sum recursive function

```
sum(0) = 0
sum(i) = sum(i-1) + i
```

this form is not closed. A closed form is `sum(n) = (n+1)*n/2`, where you only use basic operations like +-*/, power, and sometimes factorial.

For your question, how to convert a open-form formula into a closed form. The answer is *there is no general rule to transform all open-form into closed form because some of the open forms don't have equivalent closed forms.*

You may refer to [Concrete Mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201558025) for a serious treatment of this subject. The book's primary goal is to convert a large family of recursive function/open forms into their closed forms.

Answer (score 2):

An *open form* is normally given as an equation that is to be solved. For example,

```
a(0) = 1            -- base case
a(n) = b * a(n-1)   -- recurrence relation
```

To convert it into *closed form*, you *solve the recurrence relation*. In this case, repeated substitution until you reach the base case gives you

```
a(n) = b * a(n-1) = b * b + a(n-2) = ... = b * b * ... * b * a(0) = b^n
```

This is more efficient, because powers can be evaluated in logarithmic time in *n* (i.e. proportional to log *n*) whereas the original recurrence relation takes time linear in *n*.

There are many techniques used to solve recurrence relations. Some examples can be found in the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation). It is important to realise that not all recurrence relations can be solved, however - in fact, most cannot be solved (which is why programming is important!)